# c# winforms how to make foreach that calls every form (literally foreach(Form) )

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to call every form that exist in the Program/Project,
As i say in the title literally

```
foreach(Form){
    //do somting
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate all open forms owned by your application like this:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms){
    //do your thing
}
```

Note: this will only iterate the forms that have instances created.

Comment: More than child forms, Worked also on independent forms...